# How to design multi X axis graph in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I need to design graph in Kibana 4 like this, but I don't have idea as to How to set Y axis and X axis for the same.

Any pointers here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not available.  Track [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1244).